# The application trying to connect to QuickBooks is not supported while multiple instances of QuickBooks are running.

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbfc

My application Connecting to QuickBooks 2013 with QBFC 12. 
QuickBooks is running on a Server
Multiple users login to the same server and run QuickBooks from the server at the same time.
Application is also running on the Server.

Application connects to QuickBooks if only ONE user is logged in to the Server and has QB running.

If any other user logs in to the server and opens QuickBooks then the application does not connect.

```
Message Type: ERROR
Message: The application trying to connect to QuickBooks is not supported while multiple instances of QuickBooks are running.
   at Interop.QBFC11.QBSessionManagerClass.BeginSession(String qbFile, ENOpenMode openMode)
   at QBFSSyncManager.OpenQBSession()
Message: The application trying to connect to QuickBooks is not supported while multiple instances of QuickBooks are running.
   at Interop.QBFC11.QBSessionManagerClass.BeginSession(String qbFile, ENOpenMode openMode)
   at Turbo.THUB.QBProcess.QBFSSyncManager.OpenQBSession()
```

Comment: What's your question? Looks like multiple instances aren't supported.

Comment: That's probably because the connection uses a single user and that user can only be logged in once.

Comment: So in a server installation of QuickBooks, is is possible to have this scenario.

Comment: So in a server installation of QuickBooks, is is possible to have this scenario.

SESSION1: User 1 Logs in to Server1 as User1. User1 Opens QuickBooks as QBUSER1 user of QuickBooks and opens company file \\mydrive\MY COMPANY.QBW

SESSION2: User 2 Logs in to Server1 as User2. User2 open QuickBooks as Admin user of QuickBooks and opens the exact same company file \\mydrive\MY COMPANY.QBW.  User2 Now open the integrated app and this app tries to connect to the open QB company file \\mydrive\MY COMPANY.QBW

will the app in session 2 be able to connect to QB company?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use Terminal Server for QuickBooks, along with THUB, a third party program, based on the error stating, "at Turbo.THUB.QBProcess.QBFSSyncManager.OpenQBSession()". QuickBooks Enterprise supports terminal server, but it should also work with the other versions, though Intuit does not give support if you have problems. You should also check with the makers of THUB (atandra.com) to ensure the version of THUB you are using is capable of running on terminal server.

Comment: Did you ever find a real, working, tangible solution to this bug?

Answer (score 1):

Solution that I found (if it applies to your problem):
If you are running your application from within Visual Studio (any version), make sure VS is NOT running as an Administrator.
This took me hours of hair pulling, name calling, forum screaming and a broken mouse to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

My application works with multiple users, each with separate computers and separate instances of QB, all working in the same QB file via network file share.

I recommend move your application to a separate computer with its own QB instance and open the QB file remotely (not by remote desktop).

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to move Quickbooks to its own machine , and then write your application such that it receives requests from the other machines. The request can be processed and some sort of message returned. The message can be either a result set or a message letting the caller know if it worked, or if there was a problem.

Without knowing more about what you are trying to do, its hard to give specific advice.